# When Corda fully implements SGX will it solve the following potential data privacy and confidentiality leaks?

Tags: corda, sgx

Can someone confirm that SGX will solve the following and if SGX is functionality is being rolled out in Corda incrementally, when each is expected to be solved?

1. Non-validating Notaries get to see who the parties transacting are, without seeing the actual transaction data. This is a privacy leak but data confidentiality remains intact.
2. Validating Notaries get to see who the parties transacting are and the transaction data. This is a data privacy and data confidentiality leak.
3. Any party to a transaction will get to read all the transaction data and transaction parties for any dependant transaction. This could potentially be a data privacy and data confidentiality leak.

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3, you can already prevent parties from knowing which other parties are involved in transactions using [confidential identities](https://docs.corda.net/api-identity.html). In essence, you have the option of identifying transaction parties solely by an anonymous public key, rather than by well-known public key and name.

However, SGX will allow parties to validate transactions without seeing the contents. This will allow:

- Validating notaries to validate transactions without seeing the contents
- Regular parties to validate transaction chains (to ensure the states they are receiving are the result of a valid chain of transactions) without seeing the contents

Comment: Thanks Joel. Will these capabilities be released incrementally? Are there any ballpark target dates?

Comment: Also, do you know if personal data that exists within an SGX enclave (e.g. on a notary node) is still considered to be personal data (with regards to GDPR)? Thanks

Comment: The first step is to create a JVM that can run inside an SGX enclave so that contract verification can take place inside an SGX enclave. A tentative date is to have a working implementation by the end of 2018, though it won't have been integrated with Corda at that point. No idea re: GDPR :(